# Samsung smart TV cant connect through HDMI

Tags: 12.10, hdmi

In the "Sources" menu it displays as connected, but a box pops up and says:

> no signal, check cable connection and settings on connected device

My PC running Ubuntu 12.10 is set to mirror displays when I connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because you probably need to upgrade some of your drivers for your graphical card. Which garphic card do you use? NVIDIA, ATI, or INTEL? (Or a mix of many?)

Another possible source of the problem is the that the cable is somehow damaged, but I believe you have that covered :P

Comment: upgraded the drivers :)

Comment: Does your INTEL also have a graphic processor? because if it has it complicates things a little bit. Still, what type of nvidia is it?

Comment: shouldnt its a labtop :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, upgrading and reboot did the trick :)